# Typing an array of generic inferred types

Tags: typescript, generics, nested, type-inference, inference

I'm trying to create the type of an array of objects. The first and second key of this object is required to match. For example:

```
[{ 
  key1: "hi",
  key2: "world"
},{
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2
},{
  key1: true,
  key2: false
}]
```

This is what I've come up with but it doesn't exactly work. I have a generic type to define the object in the array. When calling it to generate the array type, an error is raised.

```
type ArrayItem<T> = {
  key1: T,
  key2: T
}

// This raises an error Generic Type ArrayItem requires 1 type argument
type Array = ArrayItem<T>[]
```

What is the best way to type a nested object like this (*with type inference support*)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have a finite list of possible types for `T` in `ArrayItem<T>`, there's no concrete type in TypeScript corresponding to `Array<ArrayItem<T>>`.  To represent such a thing as a non-generic type would require something like [existential types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), which TypeScript doesn't directly support.

(If you *do* have a finite list, like `ArrayItem<string> | ArrayItem<number> | ArrayItem<boolean>`, then you can just use a union like in the other answer.)

The closest you can come to this in TypeScript is as a generic type, and the best you'll do in terms of inference and compiler warnings will be to represent this as something like a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).

One way to do this is to write a generic helper function `asMyArray()` accepting a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), and the compiler will check each element of the tuple to make sure it meets the constraint.  One snag is that `{key1: "hi", key2: 2}` *does* meet the constraint if you allow things like `string | number` as `T`.  To prevent the compiler from happily accepting all pairs of types, I will try to make it infer `T` from `key1` only (see [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) to see ways to prevent inferring from a particular inference site), and then just check that `key2` matches that:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : 1]

const asMyArray = <T extends readonly any[]>(
    x: [...({ [K in keyof T]: { key1: T[K], key2: NoInfer<T[K]> } })]) =>
    x;
```

The generic type parameter `T` is a tuple corresponding to the `key1` values for each element of the passed-in array.  The passed-in array, `x`, is of a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  The `& {}` bit lowers the inference priority of `key2`.  The `[... ]` bit just prompts the compiler to infer a tuple and not an array (where it wouldn't be able to tell the different elements apart),  Lets test it out:

```
const myArray = asMyArray([{
    key1: "hi",
    key2: "world"
}, {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2
}, {
    key1: true,
    key2: false
}])
// const asMyArray: <[string, number, boolean]>(...)
```

You can see that `T` is inferred as `[string, number, boolean]`.  This succeeds, while the following, in which `T` is inferred the same way, fails:

```
const badArray = asMyArray([{
    key1: "hi", key2: 123 // error!
    // -------> ~~~~
    // number not assignable to string
}, {
    key1: 1, key2: "world" // error!
    // ----> ~~~~
    // string not assignable to number
}, {
    key1: true, key2: false
}]);
```

Looks like what you want.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXigG1sBdUqCAD2AiQBMBnKAQyRCgH4oAGKAFxQAjGQCwAKEkBjOEibA2TALIgAgunStORHFVr1mUdBFYM5AG07sQxMrgAUkqC6jUhxAHTeHAbxIA0lAAlkhQANYQIHAoUORC-pEgwkLYxAFkADQRUQBMQvDIaFhpGfgAvlDlAJRk1YS4zq7UANyS7VISsvKKALbqmtqESqoaWiAOxL5NLkkpUABEABbBC5kzOSD5iwDucOgWDAuS5dnTEq6b88LrF65J27knZxtzQsDoAK4Qt5cPQihWBYmBATnUOt0FFAAEZmMZDIisFQDcaTRJRebLVbZf4iXIAZiqdRaUAA9KSqJp9gBCSTkqAAWiZzJZrLZ7I5DPwAD9edy6RSkJ9etCMCEWEg4IokUxggBzJCsaEWaDAOBQBToUJyoA)

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with arrays can be messy, even with generic typing. It depends deeply on how your items will be used after the array is initialized. Based on your snippets, I would start creating the interfaces for each "kind" of entry in the array, to get a strong typing for each distinct set of properties.

```js
export interface FooItemType {
  key1: string,
  key2: string,
}


export interface BarItemType {
  key1: boolean,
  key2: boolean,
}
```

Then, you may create a new type that maps the interfaces you've defined before.

```js
export type ItemType = BarItemType | FooItemType;
```

After that, you may declare it as simple `ItemType` array.

```
export myArr: ItemType[] = [{ 
  key1: "hi",
  key2: "world"
},{
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2
},{
  key1: true,
  key2: false
}]
```

Although this approach is strong typed, it may result in some manual casting after you get the `myArray[i]` item from the array. Sometimes we design the "typing" before thinking about its usage in the application, so the data structure has to be designed looking for the it as a whole.