# Dependent property types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The idea I have feels pretty simple but somehow I'm stuck and wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

Consider a type like this:

```
type GenericField<T> = {
  value: T;
  onChange(value: T): void;
}
```

I would like to be able to declare an instance of type `GenericField` without having to specify `T`, as it could be inferred from the value.

```
const field: GenericField = { // Error: Generic type 'GenericField' requires 1 type argument(s).
  value: new Date(),
  onChange: (value) => { // I want value to be inferred as a Date here
    // ...
  },
};
```

The goal would be to be able to easily declare an array of these items with guaranteed type safety.

```
const fields: GenericField<unknown>[] = [
  {
    value: new Date(),
    onChange: (value: Date) => { // I have to explicitly declare the type here otherwise it is "unknown", even though it could only be a Date
      // ...
    },
  },
]
```

Is any of this possible or the generic type always has to be specified? I've already searched a lot but could only find solutions for very different scenarios. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to do only with help of an extra function. Here you can find more examples https://catchts.com/infer-arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487613/typing-an-array-of-generic-inferred-types

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wEDnvW) meet your needs?  If so then this is essentially a duplicate of the other question; if not, please [edit] your example code into something that demonstrates use cases the generic array fails to satisfy.

Comment: If you know upfront your generics, you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337050/typescript-failing-to-correctly-infer-types-from-generic-using-keyof-as-property#answer-67337548